# if Row1 = Value 1, Update other rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, if-statement

I have a little php script that goes to mySql database.

I want to look, before i insert a new record in the database, if the number (value1) equals a record in the database. Wich is also in Row1.

So i want to:

- Look if the phone number that comes in equals to a phone number in the database. If it does, than it must keep the phone number the same value, only update : longitude, latitude & timestamp.
- If the phone number equals null. Don't put any of the values in my database. No records at all.
- If the phone number is not in the database, also do nothing. Repeat it just like the value is null.

Here's my current PHP code, where i just make new records when there are any new values.

```
  <?php



$con = mysql_connect('server', 'user_name', 'pass');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
$json = $_REQUEST['data']; // recieve json from app
$data = json_Decode($json);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('$data-   >id','$data->longitude','$data->latitude','$data->timestamp')"); 

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If anyone could help me with this, it would be appreciated!

Thanx

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Have you considered the difficulty in users writing the same phone number but formatted differently? Or do you check number-fotmatting  before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned the phone number field, so I assumed is `phone_number`:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
    $data = json_decode($_REQUEST['data']);
    if($data->phonenumber){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `test` where `id`=:phone_number");
        $stmt->execute(array(':phone_number' => $data->phonenumber));
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($row_count && ($data->phonenumber != '')){
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `test` SET `longitude`=:longitude, `latitude`=:latitude, `timestamp`=:timestamp WHERE `id`=:phone_number");
            $stmt->execute(array(':longitude' => $data->longitude,':latitude' => $data->latitude,':timestamp' => $data->timestamp,':phone_number' => $data->phonenumber));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can and should check if the phone number is empty before going to the db to query.

Comment: Ehm. No the row is called id in the database. But the input from the phone number is called phonenumber

Comment: @Mihai lorga yes the row in mySQL is id. And the input that must go in that row is called phonenumber

Comment: It isn't phone_number but phonenumber

Comment: @MihaiIorga Maybe it is good to know that the mysql row is called'id' and the input value of it is 'phonenumber'

Answer (score 0):

Why go through the trouble of counting the rows found for a particular phone number? Just check for `$data->phone_number !== null` and then execute an update query *blindly*

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET longitude = :longitude, latitude = :latitude, timestamp = :timestap WHERE id = :id');
if ($stmt->execute(array(':longitude' => $data->longitude,':latitude' => $data->latitude,':timestamp' => $data->timestamp,':id' => $data->phone_number)))
{
    echo 'Updated';
}
else
{
    echo 'Couldn\'t update';
}
```

Or better yet: set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and update within a try-catch block, so you can check why the update query failed and respond accordingly. If your db engine supports it, you can use `$pdo->rollBack();` when an update has occurred when it shouldn't, too:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET longitude = :longitude, latitude = :latitude, timestamp = :timestap WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':longitude' => $data->longitude,':latitude' => $data->latitude,':timestamp' => $data->timestamp,':id' => $data->phone_number));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $pdo->rollBack();//undo any changes
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```